# Jquery Ajax Firefox not sending cookie (Chrome works)

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, google-chrome, spring-security

I'm trying to use Ajax authentication in my app and I seem to have gotten it working, except firefox does not seem to be sending the correct jessionid to the server in the "cookie" request header for subsequent requests whereas chrome does so just fine. Here is the login function:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials : true
    }
})
function sudoLogin(callback){

    $.ajax({
            url : HOST + "/ProperApp/j_spring_security_check",
            type : "POST",
            data : $("#login").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            async : false,
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.login) {
                    callback(true);
                } else {
                    callback(false);
                }
            }
        })
}
```

In the response in firefox I can see the cookie being set, and the success callback is called:

```
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=81235e7ff741e941c1e078afee5c; Path=/ProperApp; HttpOnly
```

However, in subsequent requests, such as this one, the cookie is not being sent:

```
function getUserDeets(callback){
    $.ajax({
        url : HOST+ "/ProperApp/userData",
        type : "GET",
        async : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
        success : function(data){
            callback(data);
        }
    })
}
$('#submitLogin').click(function(){
            sudoLogin(function(loggedIn){
                if(loggedIn){
                    //window.location = "sudoIndex2.php";
                    getUserDeets(function(user){
                       alert(user);
                    })

                }
                else
                    alert("login failure");
            });
        });
```

In Chromium, the request contains the cookie header, and the success callback is called correctly:

```
...
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=8129ef67b59180f9f21383cba850
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/loginSignup.php
...
```

However in Firefox, the request header does not contain the cookie header, and success is never called:

```
...
Connection  keep-alive
Host    localhost:8080
Origin  http://localhost:8000
Referer http://localhost:8000/loginSignup.php
...
```

Ive created a ajax filter on the server side, that I think should be allowing this to happen:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("origin"));
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "360");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
```

Any idea why this would work seamlessly in Chrome but not Firefox?

Comment: possibly a cross domain security issue...could always send the cookie value as data and update it client side

Comment: Any idea how I might go around this? I thought cookies were not supposed to be accessed by client side scripts.

Comment: Ater 2 1/2 days of trying everything conceivable way of getting firefox to play nice, I finally gave up and ended up using an embedded iframe of a login form hosted on the same server as the webservice. The only explanation I can think of is that Firefox is more strict with how it handles cookies in Cross Domain requests, and chrome is more lax. What really bugs me is the software isn't really communicating cross domain, just on different ports. Oh well.

Comment: different ports is cross domain

Comment: dumb question but how do you handle your session path ?:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to use native ajax or jquery ajax, then strip off async:false. it worked for me.

For further compatibility on older browsers i recommend using http://easyxdm.net/wp/. EasyXDM approach is to use an iframe hack that requires you to place an html file at the host that you're making ajax calls to. And this will be forcefully async, yes. But what's nice with this easyXDM is that you won't have to worry about cors headers.

Comment: I ended up using an iframe on the remote host for the login form. I didn't use easyxdm, it was simple enough to roll my own and use the postMessage api to send data from the iframe to the browser. So while not ideal, this approach works.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of observations first:

- The OP (original post) was dealing with cross-domain XHR because AustinR was using different ports (if any part of host, domain or port differ then the browser treats the XHR as cross-domain)
- Cross domain XHRs need proper CORS headers to be set on the server
- The javascript in the OP seemed fine except for the async:false which should ideally be set to async:true (or skipped because the setting defaults to true)

Referring to the given example I would start off with the following CORS headers:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8000"); // use a wildcard (*) as the 2nd parameter if you want to be less restrictive
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "360");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
```

The last CORS setting "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" is especially useful because it gives you a chance to troubleshoot the headers that are sent in the HTTP response by the server.

Check the response header section in the Firebug network panel for the CORS headers.
The "Origin" header of your request should match the pattern of the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header of the server response.

Comment: You was almost right. The actual problem was that i used '*' (wildcard) sign. As soon as i put direct host name - FF began to send cookie. So it seems that FF are more restrictive in that matter. You should define exact origin for 'cookie' to be send.