# A refresh command after a jquery ajax request is breaking the script in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, firefox, session-variables

So here's the thing: I'm working on a system to update the language of the website after a click on an item. It works great on Chrome and Internet explorer, desktop (Windows 8.1) or mobile but on firefox (desktop and mobile) it doesn't work if I have any kind of command to refresh the page. It only works on firefox if I remove the command and refresh the page myself.

I'm relying on session variables so I need the refresh, right?

This is what it looks like at the moment:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/global/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on("click",".button",function(){
            var language = $(this).attr("id");
            $.post("changeLanguage.php", {"language": language});
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="button" id="en">en</a>
    <a class="button" id="de">de</a>
    <a class="button" id="pt">pt</a>
    <br>
    <span id="test">
        <?php 
            if (isset($_SESSION["displayLanguage"]))
            {
                echo $_SESSION["displayLanguage"];
            }
            else
            {
                echo $_SESSION["browserLanguage"];
            } 
        ?>
    </span>
</body>
```

I've tried refreshing with:

```
location.reload();
location.reload(true);
window.location.href=window.location.href;
history.go(0);
```

and everything breaks the script in firefox but not the others.

I'm out of ideas but I'm pretty new to this so I'm hoping you guys can help.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: **Update**: Upon much closer inspection while very quickly it does seem that the page is indeed refreshing, but the `<span>` content isn't updating, so the problem must be that something in firefox isn't letting that bit of php code run again, instead of breaking the script.

Edit: **Update 2** Well even if the page refreshes on it's own following what the script tells it to, a regular refresh doesn't update the update the `<span>` content so I have to assume it doesn't break the whole script but at least the .post request to update the session variable doesn't seem to be working while the refresh request is present.

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors?

Comment: Nop... but now that I looked closer it actually seems to be refreshing the page, but it doesn't change the <span> content, so it's probably not running that bit of php again for some reason...

Comment: In my opinion there is something strange in you workflow: could it be that the $.post dosn't send the correct session id (header, cookie) to your server, so the session cannot be referenced and there will be no change in the current sessio0n, but in a new one. Please check the session in changeLanguage.php.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663409/jquery-ajax-firefox-not-sending-cookie-chrome-works

Comment: I think it's fine... It's working on everything else, it's just Firefox that's acting up and only when the refresh command is there, if I remove it and refresh the page the old fashion way (F5) it works... How can I be sure? The .php file I'm calling is basically just this `$_SESSION["displayLanguage"] = $_POST["language"];`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is when you attempt your refresh. You should wait for success from your `$.post()`. (Untested, comment if there is an issue)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/global/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on("click",".button",function(){
            var language = $(this).attr("id");
            $.post("changeLanguage.php", {"language": language})
            .error(function(jqXHR, errorStr){
                console.log("Ajax Error: " + errorStr);
                return false;
            })
            .done(function(){
                alert("Success - Reloading.");
                location.reload();
            })
            .fail(function(){
                console.log("Ajax Failed.");
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="button" id="en">en</a>
    <a class="button" id="de">de</a>
    <a class="button" id="pt">pt</a>
    <br>
    <span id="test">
        <?php 
            if (isset($_SESSION["displayLanguage"])) {
                echo $_SESSION["displayLanguage"];
            } else {
                echo $_SESSION["browserLanguage"];
            } 
        ?>
    </span>
</body>
```

Also, I would advise using FireBug. This add-on allows you to set the console log to Persist. I find this hugely valuable with AJAX testing. Often a failed Ajax causes a Link to execute. Thus you may not catch the error or display in the console. Having it persist will allow it to execute and still get the console note.

Comment: Holy crap, it works! Thank you so very much... I already use FireBug though, I'll see how I can set it Persist. Again man thanks a lot, I'd never catch this on my own *.* You da man http://i.imgur.com/BTGlceh.gif

Comment: @RicardoMarques when looking at the FireBug Console tab, you will see 3 buttons, `Clear`, `Persist`, `Profile`. Click on Persist to enable the console output to persist for each row.

Comment: Not wrapping the `location.reload()` in a callback can cause it to execute well before the AJAX request is completed. This can result in a lot of strange results, like a 408 Status. So the session variable may not have been set but the browser was already refreshing. Hence no updated `<span>`

Comment: Already set to persist thanks. My biggest problem with the `location.reload()` was that this only happened on firefox, Chrome and IE must wait by default. If it happened in all of them maybe I'd've found something by myself...

Comment: Hard to know, yet they may handle those events a bit differently. I usually start with FF and then test in Chrome, IE, Opera, mobile etc.